# iOS CLLocation difference between device models

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the Google Maps API for iOS to essentially highlight a width of coverage using the GMSPolygon.

Running the iOS simulator I get an odd behavior. Using both a iOS 9.3 build for all the testing, the map properly highlights coverage using the location simulated by the simulator on an iPhone 5S, 6, and newer.

You can see this in this screen capture that I did: [5S Highlighting](https://youtu.be/5SGidhsLP5Y)

Now when using the iPhone 4S and 5 it does not draw the GMSPolygons! [iPhone 5 Not Highlighting](https://youtu.be/5HyzhNZ1dGo)

A few things to note, I made sure that location permission were authorized on all testing and the same "city Run" simulation was used on all the testing. Again the highlighting works fine on 5S and newer devices running 9.3, but not on 4S & 5 using 9.3. **Is there a fundamental API change in the CLLocationManager between the builds for these devices?**

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [Simulator User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1), **there are some hardware and API differences in Simulator which may affect your app when testing in Simulator**.

In addition to that, please note of these hardware features that are not simulated as of iOS 8.2:

- Motion support (accelerometer and gyroscope) are unsupported.
- Audio and video input (camera and microphone) are unsupported.
- Proximity sensor
- Barometer
- Ambient light sensor

Aside from those, there are also API differences wherein Simulator APIs don’t have all the features that are available on a device such as these:

- Receiving and sending Apple push notifications
- Privacy alerts for access to Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders
- The UIBackgroundModes key
- Handoff support

  Please try going through the [Simulator User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1) for more information.